# Checking variable values and executing function within the terminal on a running nodejs server

Tags: function, node.js, variables, terminal, nowjs-sockets

I'm running a test game server on nodejs, in my terminal. What if I wanted to check the value of a variable, or execute a function? Within the terminal, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to run a debugger, to interact with our application while running.
Here you can find some: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-debugging-and-console